# How to achieve infinite scrolling backgrounds in swift

Tags: swift, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to scroll a background infinitely in my game. My app crashes when I try to do it like this:

```
@IBAction func levelClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
  let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
  let screenHeight = screenSize.height
  let imageName = "levelBackground"
  let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
  imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

  imageView.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 5500, height: screenHeight)
  view.addSubview(imageView)

  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, 
                                         target: self, 
                                       selector: Selector("moveBackground"), 
                                       userInfo: nil, 
                                        repeats: true)
}

func moveBackground() {
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.origin.x - 5,
                             y: imageView.origin.y,
                         width: 5500, 
                        height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
}
```

Here is my crash log:

> 2015-01-03 15:57:56.579 zombieSurvival[3395:708290]
>   -[zombieSurvival.firstBuildingViewController moveBackground]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e7e150
>
> 2015-01-03 15:57:56.585 zombieSurvival[3395:708290] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[zombieSurvival.firstBuildingViewController moveBackground]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e7e150'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x29dad5f7 0x374e7c77 0x29db2abd 0x29db0999 0x29ce1b88 0x2aac1a45
>   0x29d73f07 0x29d73a89 0x29d71cf3 0x29cbeb31 0x29cbe943 0x31077051
>   0x2d2b46f1 0xccc04 0xccc40 0x37a83aaf)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Comment: do you have some kind of crashlog?

Comment: Print out zombieSurvival.firstBuildingViewController.class (somewhere) and self.class (right before `timer=` ).

Comment: That just gave me more errors.

Comment: Swift is just the language, UIKit is the UI framework you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on swift, but it seems like this is not working out:

You are declaring `moveBackground` as a function inside `levelClicked`, but on your timer you are referencing `self` as target. The Class itself has no method `moveBackground`. It's only visible inside your function `levelClicked`.

Try to move the whole `moveBackground` out of `levelClicked`.

In order to make `moveBackground` work, i guess you have to give `imageView` a property.

```
@IBAction func levelClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
  let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
  let screenHeight = screenSize.height
  let imageName = "levelBackground"
  let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
  self.imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

  self.imageView.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 5500, height: screenHeight)
  view.addSubview(self.imageView)

  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, 
                                         target: self, 
                                       selector: Selector("moveBackground"), 
                                       userInfo: nil, 
                                        repeats: true)
}

func moveBackground() {
    self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.imageView.frame.origin.x - 5,
                                  y: self.imageView.origin.y,
                              width: 5500, 
                             height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
}
```

Comment: The app still crashes but this time it gave me this error: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)`

Comment: moveBackground now has no object 'imageView' in it's scope. you need a property. see my updated answer.